# Graph theory , mathematics

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I have one problem. Graph theory:

Prove that in bipartite graph $G=(X,Y,E)$  where $1 \le |X| \le |Y|$ and $\min \deg \ge \frac{(|{X}|+1)}{2}$ , each two vertices from $Y$ have the common vertices.

In my opinion it means that there is a path which is connecting each two vertices from $Y$ . But I have no idea how can I prove it.

Answer (score 1):

Assume there were two vertices $y_1, y_2$ with no common adjacent vertex on $X$. Then, since $deg(y_i) \geq \frac{(|X|+1)}{2}$

$$ |X| \geq deg(y_1) + deg(y_2) \geq |X| + 1 > |X| $$

And you reach a contradiction

Comment: Ok. But why there is inequality |X| >= deg(y1) + deg(y2) ?? I do not understand this last steps , please explain me why you reached this

Comment: Since it's a bipartite graph, every edge reaching $y_i$ must also reach some $x \in X$. We're also assuming $y_1, y_2$ have no common neighbor, so the sum of their degrees must be, at most, $|X|$

Comment: In other words, let $X_i$ be the neighbours of $y_i$ in $X$. Then $$ X_1 \cup X_2 \subset X, X_1 \cap X_2 = \emptyset \implies |X| \geq |X_1| + |X_2| = |X_1 \cup X_2| $$

Comment: Ok and the inequality deg(y1) + deg(y2) >= |X|+1 is due of assupmtion ?? And why in the end this all is bigger than |X| ??

Comment: Ok the last inequality that this all is bigger than |X| is clear definitely. But this |X| +1 is coming from assumption yes ?

Comment: Ok and what do you think about this one : prove if the size of graph ( each graph) is larger than [(n-1)(n-2)]/2  it is connected  ( means that always there is exist a path which is connecting each two vertives ) . I only noticed that [(n-1)(n-2)]/2 equal ( n-1 ,2 ) - symbol of nethon , but next i have no idea

Comment: $deg(y_1) + deg(y_2) \geq |X| + 1$ does indeed use the hyphotesis that $deg(y_i) \geq \frac{|X|+1}{2}$.
I think you should open a new post for the other question.